# phpMyAdmin File Limit (already edited php.ini)

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to import a 151 MB database into phpMyAdmin and am getting the error "You probably tried to upload a file that is too large. Please refer to documentation for a workaround for this limit."

I've already edited php.ini with values of upload_max_filesize, memory_limit and post_max_size that more than accommodate this file. Is there anything else I can do to troubleshoot?

Comment: are you using xampp server? or wamp?

Comment: What values did you use for `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size`? The latter must be larger than the former because of encoding as the file is being sent.

Comment: I've used these values... post_max_size = 208M
upload_max_filesize 342M

Comment: Where exactly are you seeing the error? You probably want to swap the size values as post size should be larger than upload.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try setting `max_execution_time` and `max_input_time` with higher values.

```
max_execution_time = 90
max_input_time = 120
```

You might want to try `memory_limit` as well and don't forget to restart the server.

Comment: It was restarting the server! I forgot to restart the server. Thank you